# How is an ICC profile embedded or built into an image?

Tags: color, color-management

If I were to analyze or change an [ICC profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) embedded in an image, how should I proceed?

I'd also be glad to understand how an "end-user" is able to create these with a [tristimulus colorimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tristimulus_colorimeter) or a [spectrophotometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrophotometer) and if/how this new profile can be added to a color capturing device (i.e. a camera).

My curiosity comes from images that were taken by a professional photographer. When I open them in GIMP, there's a pop-up referring "there is an embedded ICC profile" and if I "would like to convert the image to RGB (sRGB built-in)". I always convert all of them before using them, since the colors are slightly improved.

This is the image as it was provided by the photographer:
[image: No ICC]

And this is after the embedded ICC profile was applied:
[image: With ICC]

Comment: I would take http://www.littlecms.com/ for a spin

Comment: @joojaa This is great! They actually say: "lcms is a CMM engine; it implements fast transforms between ICC profiles". And by their trial of the professional solution, they provide a lot of options ("input for RGB, Gray, and CMYK spaces", "intents", "destination color space", etc.)... I never imagined that it could be so vast.

Comment: The [international color consortium](http://www.color.org/index.xalter) defines 4 transformation intents for the colors that can not fit the gamut, read the tutorial.

Comment: @joojaa actually, in their own program they have a small description associated to all of the 7 types of "rendering intents" we can choose from when converting.

Comment: hey allow for more intents and different white point/ blackpoint combinations. (adobe thus has 3*4 intents)

Comment: @joojaa I am impressed with the quantity of destination spaces they provide, for the conversions I tested there are shocking differences when ProPhotoRGB is used, [it's very hard to tell the differences when different intents are applied though], EDIT: in some situations intents are also very noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that littlecms, [suggested by *joojaa* in a comment above](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/175/how-is-an-icc-profile-embedded-or-built-into-an-image#comment247_175) is very complete in dealing with the ICC profiles.

I did a few tests in their color translator program with different destination color spaces and the differences are great as you can see:

Original

[image: Original]

sRGB-like

[image: sRGB]

adobeRGB1998 (it seems it's the original color space)

[image: adobeRGB]

appleRGB

[image: apple]

And the most desirable results in my case are within the ProPhotoRGB color space:

[image: prophoto]

linearProPhotoRGB

[image: linearProPhoto]

All of the above were following an automatic *rendering intent* but other *intents* bring slight variations (samples applied together with linearProPhotoRGB destination color space):

Absolute Colorimetric

[image: ICC absolute colorimetric]

Legacy Unadapted Absolute Colorimetric

[image: Legacy]

I also realized that GIMP was actually restoring the original profile (not the opposite as I thought, i.e. instead of applying an embedded ICC profile, it was taking it off) and with this littlecms, now it does seem much simpler to "translate" color spaces than I thought.